# Convert comma separated CSV file to tab separated using Java

Tags: java, csv, tabs

I am trying to convert a comma-separated CSV file to a tab-separated CSV file using Java. However, a few of the values inside the file itself have commas. Please refer to example below:

```
Direct - House,Bayer House Advertiser,537121661,,160 x 600,Bayer US Publisher,537121625,Bayer.com,537224178,160x600_MyeBay_US,538146889,2015-11-18,"8,455,844",0,0,0,0.000000,USD,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000

Direct - House,Bayer House Advertiser,537121661,,160 x 600,Bayer US Publisher,537121625,Bayer.com,537224178,160x600_Search_SLR,538146895,2015-11-18,"20,175,240",30,0,0,0.000000,USD,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
```

So can anyone help me how to handle these values?

Comment: So what is the pattern? You mentioned about few of the values having comma itself? Are these values only number values? Is that all a single line or multiple lines?

Comment: @Raf: I ahve updated the records now. There are 2 records above. Also the values causing the issue are numbers. For example, "8,455,844".

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to rely on pattern that does not change. You did mention that you have issue with numbers having comma as thousand separators. I see that in your lines those numbers are enclosed with a double quote. Based on the following assumptions:

1. The number is enclosed in double quotes
2. There is only one of such number in each line (if more than one, then find all the pairs of double quotes and store them in arrays or list, and check to make sure index do not fall in the range for each)

Then you an do the following:

1. Get first index of the double quote i.e. 154
2. Get the second/last index of the double quote i.e. 159
3. Replace all commas with \t provided that index of comma is less than first index of first double quote or index of comma is greater than last index of double quote (this should skip the comma of number to be replaced with \t)

The following code does exactly the above for you:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvToTabConvertor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\test_java\\csvtotab.txt"); 
        List<String> processedLines = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
            String line; 
            StringBuilder builder; 
            while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                builder = new StringBuilder(line); 

                //find number in double quote - assuming there is only one number with double quotes
                int doubleQuoteIndexStart = builder.indexOf("\""); 
                int doubleQuoteIndexLast = builder.lastIndexOf("\""); 

                //for each line, find all indexes of comma
                int index = builder.indexOf(",");

                //previous used to when there is consecutive comma
                int prevIndex = 0; 

                while (index >= 0) {
                    if(index < doubleQuoteIndexStart || index > doubleQuoteIndexLast) {
                        builder.setCharAt(index, '\t'); 
                    }

                    //get next index of comma
                    index = builder.indexOf(",", index + 1);

                    //check for consecutive commas
                    if(index != -1 && (prevIndex +1) == index) {
                        builder.setCharAt(index, ' ');
                        //get next index of comma
                        index = builder.indexOf(",", index + 1);
                    }
                }

                //add the line to list of lines for later storage to file
                processedLines.add(builder.toString());
            }

            //close the output stream
            br.close(); 

            //write all the lines to the file
            File outFile = new File("C:\\test_java\\csvtotab_processed.txt");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFile); 
            for(int i = 0; i < processedLines.size(); i++) {
                writer.println(processedLines.get(i));
            }

            writer.close(); 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Input file containing the following lines:

```
Direct - House,eBay House Advertiser,537121661,,160 x 600,eBay US Publisher,537121625,eBay.com,537224178,160x600_MyeBay_US,538146889,2015-11-18,"8,455,844",0,0,0,0.000000,USD,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
Direct - House,eBay House Advertiser,537121661,,160 x 600,eBay US Publisher,537121625,eBay.com,537224178,160x600_Search_SLR,538146895,2015-11-18,"20,175,240",30,0,0,0.000000,USD,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
```

The processed output file is as follow:

```
Direct - House  eBay House Advertiser   537121661       160 x 600   eBay US Publisher   537121625   eBay.com    537224178   160x600_MyeBay_US   538146889   2015-11-18  "8,455,844" 0   0   0   0.000000    USD 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Direct - House  eBay House Advertiser   537121661       160 x 600   eBay US Publisher   537121625   eBay.com    537224178   160x600_Search_SLR  538146895   2015-11-18  "20,175,240"    30  0   0   0.000000    USD 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Modify the above code and its logic to fulfil any further needs.

Comment: @user1496783 you are welcome, if the answer helped resolve your issue then you have the option to mark the answer as **accepted**, you can read more in here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: just used it for my own problem, worked fine too! @Raf cheers I wanted to replace commas with tabs, and then full stops with commas, so I just copied /pasted the code and run it into the very same main. The first output was the second input. Not the most elegant code, but did the job.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, huge claps for the answer. I have a question - How can I read multiple files and perform the same operation? Want to make the changes in the same code to read multiple files.

Comment: Pretty easy actually! Create a new method with the content of try/catch block and then call that method for each file. In java you can open a directory and then loop through its contents (i.e. files and directories).